# Can we calculate bond enthalpies for each bond in a supercell of a disordered AB crystal using DFT?

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystal-structure, crystallography, solid-state-physics, disorder

Apart from using [Bader charge analysis](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1444/5) or energy of formation estimation, I wonder if there is a way to compute the bond energy of constituent bonds in a crystal using density functional theory.

Let's say I have a disordered $AB$ crystal. There could be multiple possible arrangements of $A$ and $B$ given the disorder, thereby resulting in many possible supercells. Is it possible to find the bond strength for each bond in one such supercell?

Comment: Maybe looking at LOBSTER and COHP type analysis?

Comment: @TristanMaxson, checked their website, this is it! Thanks.

Comment: I would answer but I know almost nothing about it.  Maybe you can self answer eventually

Comment: Hitanshu, are you at the stage where you might be able to write a self-answer? If not, what is the obstacle for you?

Comment: @NikeDattani, not yet. Will try soon.

Comment: From the comments, it seems like the question can be answered. In the meantime, I think it should be closed to free up the unanswered queue.